# How locate ::before::after in html with help selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium, pseudo-element, selenide

```
::before
::after
```

the only thing I can grab is these two lines

[image]

how to check their existence in the html using java

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.